# Применить маску через Action

Tags: photoshop, action

У меня есть около сотни изображений на которые нужно наложить маску. Маска везде одинаковая.

Делал через экшены потом через "Пакетную обработку" планировал выводить. Пробовал переносить из соседнего файла слой маски. Не работает, не записывается действие. Попробовал просто создать маску-прямоугольник и применять её через экшн. Действие так же не записывается и как следствие маска не накладывается.

Позволяет ли вообще Экшены записывать такие действия(перенос слоя из соседнего файла и наложение маски), или это делается как-то иначе?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел немного костыльное решение которое подходит в случае векторной маски.
Действие записывается, только если скопировать точки фигуры в буффер, и записать действие вставки при выделении слоя 0. Впринципе то, что и нужно, но перед запуском процесса, необходимо вручную копировать точки.